# Could Ingenuity survive if Perseverance failed?

Tags: mars, landing, perseverance, failure, ingenuity

For the purposes of this question, we will assume that they both landed successfully. Ingenuity was deployed properly. Then, Perseverance drove away, and then Perserverance say hit a large rock and failed. Could Ingenuity survive on its own? Or does it rely on Perserverance?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. Perseverance is the communications relay for Ingenuity.

Ingenuity uses essentially ZigBee to communicate, the same protocol that possibly your smart bulbs use. ZigBee has a range of about 300m line-of-sight without obstructions which is just a tiny bit too short for communicating with Earth.

Comment: Ingenuity [pushes a bit more power than a typical ZigBee and "*The link is designed to relay data at over-the-air rates of 20 kbps or 250 kbps over **distances of
up to 1000 m***"](http://hdl.handle.net/2014/46229) which is still a bit too short of Earth

Comment: Indeed. Note that my answer is a bit tongue-in-cheek, since of course Perseverance also (usually) does not communicate with Earth (although it can in a pinch) but with one of the Martian relays. They're not quite as far away as Earth, but still orders of magnitude farther than 1000m.

Comment: Imagine a whole planet free of EM noise-generating devices!

Comment: All the unfortunate sub-surface Martian homes finding their smart bulbs going haywire :(

Comment: As we say on explainxkcd.com: {{citation needed}}